# access_token not present in /oauth/access_token response

Tags: support, api-v2, oauth2, php

When using the explicit OAuth authentication for apps, I have problems receiving the access_token. A user goes to /approve and is then forwarded to approve the app. When redirected back to my site I catch the code parameter and do the final POST to get the access_token. However I can't find it in the response object!

This is my PHP routes file:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

Route::get('/approve', function () {
    header('Location: https://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=12345&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=https://mysite.com/approved');
});

Route::get('/approved', function (Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();    
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token/json', [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => 12345,
            'client_secret' => 'apfeusenfpuansefpunapfn((',
            'code' => \Request::get("code"),
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://mysite.com/approved'
        ]
    ]);

    dd($response); // dumping the response gives no trace of access_token
});
```

- Running getStatusCode() on the response object gives a 200 All OK.
- Dumping the full response, body, or headers give me no reference of the access_token whatsoever.
- I tried swapping "form_params" to "query" same result.
- Adding "json" to the API URL gives no change.
- I'm using Guzzle 6.

Any ideas, where did I go wrong?

---

Update: I managed to get the access_token with cURL so I am assuming I am not using guzzle correctly...

```
function RequestToken($code)
{
    $params = array(
        "code" => $code,
        "client_id" => 12345,
        "client_secret" => 'agibsgiasbgoaigbasorgibas((',
        "redirect_uri" => 'https://mysite.com/approved'
    );
    $postString = rawurldecode(http_build_query( $params ));

    $ch = curl_init('https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token');

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString );

    $httpResponse = curl_exec( $ch );

    parse_str($httpResponse, $output);

    return $output["access_token"];
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the code may not be following a redirect or something. Try looking at PHP libraries to see how they do OAuth2. Also, it doesn't look like you are un GZipping the response, but I'm rusty with PHP and not familiar with Guzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Unpack response content with $response->getBody()->getContents().

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

Route::get('/approve', function () {
    header('Location: https://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=12345&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=https://mysite.com/approved');
});

Route::get('/approved', function (Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();    
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token/json', [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' => 12345,
            'client_secret' => 'apfeusenfpuansefpunapfn((',
            'code' => \Request::get("code"),
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://mysite.com/approved'
        ]
    ]);

    dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
    // {"access_token":"sdoginGDpng3pnGPNGDDGGDP))","expires":86399}
});
```